# Finding derivative of given function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

*f(t)* = $\int_{t^2}^{4}\sqrt{\cos(x)+12}\;dx$

Rearranging limits of integration...

$f(t) = -\int_{4}^{t^2}\sqrt{\cos(x)+12}\;dx$

Taking derivative...

$f'(t) = -\sqrt{\cos(t^2)+12}\; - (1/2)({\cos(t^2)+12})^{-1/2}\; - \sin{(t^2)} \cdot 2t$

Is this answer correct, or am I taking "too much" of the derivative? Should I only be taking the derivative of $t^2$? Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you "took too much derivative" here:

We need only apply the chain rule: If
$$F'(t)= - \int_4^{\large u(t) = t^2}\sqrt{\cos x + 12} \, dx $$ $$\implies F(t) = -\Big[\underbrace{t^2}_{\large u(t)}\Big]' \sqrt{\cos (t^2) + 12} = -\underbrace{2t}_{\large u'(t)}\sqrt{\cos (t^2) + 12}$$

Comment: Very nice indeed +)

Comment: Took too much derivative. I haven't heard that expression before.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

If
$$F(t)=\int_a^{u(t)}f(x)dx$$
then by chain rule
$$F'(t)=f(u(t))u'(t)$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $-\sqrt{\cos{(t^2)}+12}\cdot 2t$. See [Leibniz's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement).